# Using seismic base isolators in light, flexible buildings

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, earthquake-engineering

Using seismic base isolators dissipate a great deal of energy that would enter to a structure, but at the same time they increase the natural period of vibration of the structure. Now, if we had a light and flexible building, does using seismic base isolators create a negative effect from this point of view, since a flexible building's period is already high and base isolator makes it even more causing it to shake much longer?

Comment: Which is worse longer shaking or catastrophic damage?

Comment: Your comment is misleading. Longer shaking can also be the source of catastrophic damage.

Comment: Then fitting isolators that increase the period is not a solution - based on your analysis. Why do building regs in certain countries therefore require them?

Comment: Seismic base isolators are a good solution for many buildings such as heavy concrete buildings. But for the light and flexible buildings as I stated in my question, there may be a problem, as I stated which is what I am asking to understand from someone knowledgeable.

Comment: Design and implementation of seismic isolators depends strongly on the expected frequency and magnitude of local disturbance. isolating from subway trains is radicallly different from isolating from earth tremors, for example.